# sankey chart is not plotting when we have source data and target data is matched tried in highcharts and d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

I plotted sankey chart in D3.js and tried in highcharts too, when the data is same in source and target then the chart is not plotting. How to overcome this limitation.

```
    var graph = {
    "links": [
              {"source":"1","target":"1","value":"1.7"},
              {"source":"1","target":"2","value":"1.5"},
              {"source":"2","target":"3","value":"1.2"},
              {"source":"3","target":"4","value":"0.3"}
    ] ,
    "nodes": [
              {"name":"Energy"},
              {"name":"Industrial Processes"},
              {"name":"Electricity and heat"},
              {"name":"Electricity"}
    ] }
```

I tried in High Charts. I found the same problem when data is like

```
    series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [{
    from: 'total',
    to: 'Useful kinetic energy',
    weight: 56,
    outgoing: true
    }, {
        from: 'total',
        to: 'total',
        weight: 27,
        outgoing: true
    }, {
        from: 'total',
        to: 'Sound loss',
        weight: 17,
        outgoing: true
    }]
```

Please suggest me how to overcome this problem, i.e when we have same data in source and target

Comment: Why do you want to have the same data in the source and target? If it's not the same it works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/97s40re1/

Comment: When it is not same it will works fine. But the data which I am passing is from the server dynamically and using same data to plot different types of charts. We shouldn't skip the object of same data having in source and target. That's why I need solution or alternative to plot sankey with same  data.

Comment: Ok, however same data is not plotted even when you leave it. So you can have it in a data array but filter it when passing to highcharts. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kvz5ywou/1/

Comment: I solved it by adding space after target column like   {"source":"1","target":"1 ","value":"1.7"}